# Can you explain the counter in the Key derivation function of PACE?

Tags: protocol-design, sha-256

I try to understand the [PACE-Protocol](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/BSI/Publications/TechGuidelines/TR03110/TR-03110_v2.1_P3pdf.pdf), especially the Key Derivation Function in ECDH on page 33.

Can someone explain me, what the Counter is good for? Often there are iteration counters in KDF - but here are usual Hash-Functions (like SHA-256) are used as KDF. So there is no iteration. Is this something like a message counter so that we create a new Hash for every new message?

Comment: Welcome to crypto, Thomas. Sorry for the detour :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter is used to distinguish the different (session) keys used in the protocols. A relatively standard KDF is used, [KDF2](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoKDFs.html#kdf2). Note that only a single iteration is needed and that no `OtherInfo` has been defined, so the specification of KDF2 may look more complex than it is in the PACE protocol. A 32 bit counter is of course overkill for the protocol, but that's just how the counter has been defined.

So you have the counter valued 1, encoded as `00000001` in hexadecimals as input for the encryption key, and a counter valued 2, encoded as `00000002` for the MAC key.

Some of this is explained in the very first sentence of A.2.3, page 33 (the definitions of KDF<sub>MAC</sub> and KDF<sub>ENC</sub>).

Note that this counter is entirely different from the Send Sequence Counter used within the secure messaging protocol. That counter is either 64 or 128 bits in size.